How to download files from remote server in Apache Guacamole SSH connection type
Im using Apache Guacamole server version 1.5.3 to create SSH session for users via web browser, in order to communicate with the server I'm using the common-js api:
...
const tunnel = new Guacamole.WebSocketTunnel(wsURL);
tunnel.receiveTimeout = 60000;
tunnel.onerror = error => {
    showError(`Connection to the remote server failed.`, error);
}
const guac = new Guacamole.Client(tunnel);
const display = guac.getDisplay();
display.scale(1);
....

I'm able to create a tunnel and to communicate with the SSH server and upload files, but I'm unable to make download files working.
I saw that there is an event which fired when new file is created, that I can use to initiate file download in the browser, but I can't make this event fire:
/**
     * Fired when a file stream is created. The stream provided to this event
     * handler will contain its own event handlers for received data.
     * 
     * @event
     * @param {Guacamole.InputStream} stream The stream that will receive data
     *                                       from the server.
     * @param {String} mimetype The mimetype of the file received.
     * @param {String} filename The name of the file received.
     */
    this.onfile = null;

I tried to set
guac.onfile = function downloadFile(fileStream, mimetype, filename) {
    console.log("ONFILE called", fileStream, mimetype, filename)
}

According to do docs here, the way to do it is to use a shell script guacctl that suppose to send some opcodes to the tunnel, I tried to scp the script to the remote server and run ./guacctl -d /path/to/file, but it does nothing, like nothing listen to the event.
Is there anyone here who had a chance to implement this? Most of the examples and guides I see in the web regarding file transfer is for RDP or VNC when you simply drag and drop the file and guacamole does everything behind the scene.
Question is, what are the steps I need to do in order to manually initiate file download using onfile event, or how can I make guacctl working? I feel like I'm missing something.

Consider using https://github.com/hoophq/hoop as a better alternative, should be easier
